# How do I close an off-topic question I posted earlier ?

Tags: support, questions, close

Some days ago I posted [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/183514/how-can-i-prevent-maximized-windows-from-overlapping-conky-window). Now I would like it to be closed since I understand it doesn't belong here.

I have posted it in SU which I think is the right place.

Can someone help me in closing it as off-topic ?

Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: It's been closed for you.

Comment: You can delete your own questions before they get any answers too.

Answer (score 2):

The next time you could just flag it with "Requires Moderator attention" and a short message.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know you need to have a bit more reputation:

> **250** Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions

from the [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq)